# Grouping in a generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

I have a generic list:

```
  List<Test> lstReport = new List<Test>();
  lstReport.Add(new Test { ID = 1, Category = "Hot work", Approver = "Praveen" });
  lstReport.Add(new Test { ID = 1, Category = "Civil work", Approver = "Praveen" });
  lstReport.Add(new Test { ID = 1, Category = "Others", Approver = "Praveen" });
  lstReport.Add(new Test { ID = 4, Category = "Hot work", Approver = "Praveen" });
  lstReport.Add(new Test { ID = 5, Category = "Critical work", Approver = "Praveen" });
```

Now I want to take unique rows from the generic list by the ID value.
For eg, I need to group the rows having same **ID** and if the existence of **ID's** more than once, then its **Category** field has to be changed to "**Grouped**".

How can I write this expression?

Comment: Do you have the list of `Approver` in group or some other logic? Or it same for all?

Comment: This design is a little odd by the way because you'll lose the information of the individual Category and Approver fields when you group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Works:**

```
    var QueryResult = (from x in lstReport
                        group x by x.ID into res
                        select new Test
                        {
                            ID = res.Key,
                            Category = res.Count() > 1 ? "Grouped" : res.First().Category,
                            Approver = res.First().Approver
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: actually no, this create new list with anonymous types doesn't change the original items

Comment: i didn't have Test class that's why i removed it. Edited.

Comment: @PraveenVR On thing still missing is what do you want to do with Approver . you can add -- Approver = res.First().Approver --

Comment: yes , I want it the Approver name too in the result

Comment: @PraveenVR What if the approvers are different?

Comment: @PraveenVR Edited to take the first approver. If you have another scenario please mention it.

Comment: It works for my scenario.. @Ben, The Approver name will be common for all the rows having same ID

Comment: @user3185569-Thank u very much for ur help

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Test> lstReport = new List<Test>();

...

var groups = lstReport.GroupBy(i => i.ID).ToList();

foreach(var group in groups) {
    var items = group.ToList();
    if(items.Count > 1)
        items.ForEach(i => { i.Category = "Grouped"; });
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the first answer that actually does what was asked!

Comment: the logic is correct but you have several syntactical mistakes and also `ForEach` is an method on `List<T>` you can't use it on a `IGrouping` interface

Comment: Thank you for paying attention. I think it should be right now. Wrote the code from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var q = from r in lstReport
group r by r.ID into g
select new Test{ID=g.Key, Category = g.Count()>1? "Grouped" : g.Min(Category)};
```

also you can have g.Max(...) or g.Min(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to group objects based on some property:

```
var list = lstReport.GroupBy(t => t.ID);
```

This will return a new collection with 3 items: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`; which basically means a collection containing a collection with one or more items.

Then you can iterate over that new collection and check if each item contains more than one subitem; if it does, then iterate over the subitems and modify the Category value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx